# Linking the accounts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using two different Signin methods for my app
1. Google SignIn
2. Phone number authentication
I want to include these two accounts in one account
Is it possible and how?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Follow the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking If you can't get it to work, post back with the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the above link  "Service Unavailable" is raising

Comment: As said: if you can't get it to work, post back with the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read that last link please, as it explains why this is useful, and how to maximize the chance we can help you better than the documentation can.